# Securely send password to LDAP server using PHP

Tags: php, ssl, ldap

What I am trying to do is set up a login screen. I collect the user's credentials and verify it using an ldap server before allowing the user to take a quiz.

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_POST['user'];
$domain = 'DOMAIN';
$password = $_POST['password'];
$ldapserver="ldap.example.server";
$ldapport=389;
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldapserver,$ldapport);

if ($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap,"{$user}@{$domain}", $password)){
    $_SESSION["user"] = '$user';
    header('Location: quiz.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: login.html');
}

?>
```

When I use wireshark to sniff the packets, i can see the username and password clearly. Is there a way to bind to an LDAP server without sending the password in plain text? The site doesnt have https. The owner does not want to buy a SSL certificate, nor is he interest in a self-signed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your ldap server support ldaps and have a certificate?  That would be the easiest way to do this and your site wouldn't need a certificate. You'd just change your code slightly. Assuming your server uses the default ldaps port:

```
$ldapserver = 'ldaps://ldap.example.server';
$ldapport = 636;
```

Comment: So i was able to connect to the server but not able to bind. The credentials are the same as they were before. Any ideas on why i cant bind?

Comment: Hmm, does the hostname in `$ldapserver` match the CN on the certificate?

Comment: I have no idea. I dont have access to the server but I'll check to see. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)